# Set property value during launch in spring batch

Tags: java, spring-batch, batch-processing

I am using spring batch 3.0. I have a scenario where I need to run approximately 1000s of jobs with 1 property value and same jobs with different property value. Is there a way to set property of job during Launch or scheduling time rather than in job configuration. Or any other way to achieve such functionality without replicating 1000s of job.

```
<batch:job id="job_A" parent="simpleJob">
        <batch:step id="A" parent="simpleStep">
            <batch:tasklet>
                <bean id="bA" class="ClassA" scope="step">
                        <property name="downloadFileA" value="false" />
                </bean>     
            </batch:tasklet>
         </batch:step>  
</batch:job>
```

And again same job with property value as true.

```
<batch:job id="job_A" parent="simpleJob">
        <batch:step id="A" parent="simpleStep">
            <batch:tasklet>
                <bean id="bA" class="ClassA" scope="step">
                        <property name="downloadFileA" value="true" />
                </bean>     
            </batch:tasklet>
         </batch:step>  
</batch:job>
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: check quartz scheduler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use job parameters which get passed to the job launcher and are then accessible from the steps in your job.

When launching a job, you can do something like this...

```
JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
    .addString("downloadFileA", "true")
    .toJobParameters();

JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
```

You can then inject the jobParameter in your step...

```
@Autowired
@Value("#{jobParameters[downloadFileA]}")
String downloadFileA;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should take a look at the Decider :

## From spring batch documentation :

> In some situations, more information than the ExitStatus may be
>   required to decide which step to execute next. In this case, a
>   JobExecutionDecider can be used to assist in the decision.
>
> ```
> public class MyDecider implements JobExecutionDecider {
>     public FlowExecutionStatus decide(JobExecution jobExecution, StepExecution stepExecution) {
>         if (someCondition) {
>             return "FAILED";
>         }
>         else {
>             return "COMPLETED";
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> In the job configuration, a "decision" tag will specify the decider to
>   use as well as all of the transitions.
>
> ```
> <job id="job">
>     <step id="step1" parent="s1" next="decision" />
>
>     <decision id="decision" decider="decider">
>         <next on="FAILED" to="step2" />
>         <next on="COMPLETED" to="step3" />
>     </decision>
>
>     <step id="step2" parent="s2" next="step3"/>
>     <step id="step3" parent="s3" />
> </job>
>
> <beans:bean id="decider" class="com.MyDecider"/>
> ```

So in other words you should create a class that implements the JobExecutionDecider interface and then return a result based on your if-else test, and use this class in your spring batch xml configuration. Voilà!